# Inherit Icon from main form into subforms in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have a main form in a visual studio 2010 application which has a logo as an icon.  I have built multiple other forms that are opened on button click events...etc.  Is there a way for all my subforms to inherit the logo of the main form or do I just manually assign it in each form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a `BaseForm` class, directly derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, set its `Icon` property, and then derive all your other forms from this one.

Cheers

Comment: Complete walkthrough here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z3efhd2(v=vs.110).aspx